# Value changes on scroll UITableView

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UITableView with a button in that's toggled depending on whether a user 'favorites' a post or not. Everything works well, except for when the table view is scrolled, the button changes. Here's my code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    guard let feed = self.feed else {
        return 0
    }
    return feed.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if feed!.count > 9 {
        if indexPath.row == feed!.count - 1 {
            self.loadMorePosts()
        }
    }

    if hasImageAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
        return imageCellAtIndexPath(indexPath)

    } else {
        return basicCellAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    }

}

func hasImageAtIndexPath(indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    let post = self.feed?[indexPath.row]

    if post?.image?.isEmpty == false {
        return true
    }

    return false
}

func imageCellAtIndexPath(indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> PostCellImage {
    let cell:PostCellImage = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("imageCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PostCellImage


    if let post = self.feed?[indexPath.row] {
        let likedPost = post.hasFavorited

        if likedPost == true {
            if let favoriteCount = post.favoriteCount {
                let count = String(favoriteCount)
                cell.likeButton.setTitle(count, forState: .Normal)
                cell.likeButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "liked"), forState: .Normal)
                cell.likeButton.setTitleColor(UIColorFromRGB("A61224"), forState: .Normal)
                cell.likeButton.addTarget(self, action: "unfavoritePost:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
                cell.likeButton.tag = post.id!
            }
        } else {
            if let favoriteCount = post.favoriteCount {
                let count = String(favoriteCount)
                cell.likeButton.setTitle(count, forState: .Normal)
                cell.likeButton.addTarget(self, action: "favoritePost:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
                cell.likeButton.tag = post.id!
            }
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

Favorited Posts Array

```
var favoritedPosts =  [Int]()
```

Table View

```
if let likedPost = post.hasFavorited {
    if likedPost == true {
        self.favoritedPosts.append(indexPath.row)             
        print(self.favoritedPosts)
    }
}

if self.favoritedPosts.contains(indexPath.row) {
    let count = String(post.favoriteCount)
    cell.likeButton.setTitle(count, forState: .Normal)
    cell.likeButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "liked"), forState: .Normal)
    cell.likeButton.setTitleColor(UIColorFromRGB("A61224"), forState: .Normal)
    cell.likeButton.addTarget(self, action: "unfavoritePost:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    cell.likeButton.tag = post.id!     
} else {
    let count = String(post.favoriteCount)
    cell.likeButton.setTitle(count, forState: .Normal)
    cell.likeButton.addTarget(self, action: "favoritePost:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    cell.likeButton.tag = post.id!        
}
```

Comment: This is often a tiny gotcha that i think gets everyone once or a few times. i assume you are using the `dequeReusableCells` method. When you scroll, that method will keep spitting out cells that are already on the table  but were outside of the window for efficiency reason. When you use a condition to set some ui elements if you do not provide values for every element in the cell it will continue to use the old values of the cell thus giving unintended results. Im not 100% sure this is your issue i would recommend including the whole `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method in your question.

Comment: Just added that code

Comment: you should add `else` part to all your nested `if` statements to avoid any problem caused by reusing of cells. Please try this.

Comment: Hey @AlexSmith not sure if you still haven't solved this. Please have a look at my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/37826482/6458001 below. If this works for you, please mark it as correct so it may help some other developer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your `UITableViewCell` `PostCellImage` subclass you should override `prepeareForReuse` function - to turn cell to default mode.

Swift:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()

    //set cell to initial state here 
    //set like button to initial state - title, font, color, etc.
}
```

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad to help.

Answer (score 6):

This might be cased by the table view cell reuse. It turns out that your code set the likeButton.image when the post is a favorited post but did not remove the image when the post is not a favorited one. So when the first time each cell is loaded into tableView every thing works fine. However, when scrolling the tableView, when those cells with favorite image set moves out of the screen area, they will be reused for the cell scrolling in. Thus if this kind of cell is reused by a post that is even not favorited, the image will still be there.

There is a prepareForReuse method for UITableViewCell, it gives you the chance to reset the contents before a cell is being reused.

Comment: I can't seem to find the prepareForReuse method... Anyone else have this problem? Perhaps this is why the question's bounty says, "The current answer(s) are out-of-date and require revision given recent changes."

Comment: @penatheboss: this method is a method of UITableViewCell methods. override it in you UITableViewCell subclass.

Comment: @truongky oh! That makes more sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

- You need to completely reset the appearance for normal case here.
- Reason is you can't be sure which state of the button you get when
  cells are reused.
- When you receive a dequeued cell, it might have a
  button with 'liked'/'not-liked' state.
- Completing the appearance with two commented out lines in the `else` clause will resolve your problem.

  ```
   if self.favoritedPosts.contains(indexPath.row) {
      let count = String(post.favoriteCount)
      cell.likeButton.setTitle(count, forState: .Normal)
      cell.likeButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "liked"), forState: .Normal)
      cell.likeButton.setTitleColor(UIColorFromRGB("A61224"), forState: .Normal)
      cell.likeButton.addTarget(self, action: "unfavoritePost:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
      cell.likeButton.tag = post.id!
  } else {
      let count = String(post.favoriteCount)
      cell.likeButton.setTitle(count, forState: .Normal)

      // Uncomment these two lines and add proper values for image / color to resolve your problem
      // cell.likeButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "not-liked-yet"), forState: .Normal)
      // cell.likeButton.setTitleColor(UIColorFromRGB("A67832"), forState: .Normal)

      cell.likeButton.addTarget(self, action: "favoritePost:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
      cell.likeButton.tag = post.id!        
  }
  ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: For some reason, I'm having the same issue even with commenting out those two lines.

Comment: @AlexSmith you are not supposed to comment out those. Those are the solution to your problem. Please read my last point carefully. **Completing the appearance with two commented out lines in the else clause will resolve your problem.** You need to provide the normal (unliked) case values for image and color here.

Comment: @AlexSmith I just reformatted my answer. Have a look at it. This should clarify what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

You can try prepareForReuse or try to set unlike image in the case `likedPost == false`